# Overflow: scroll results in the hidden columns of the table not being rendered. What is going wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am incorporating react-grid into an existing flask app. To do so I had to use a custom webpack configuration to compile the app. I was able to successfully render react components but when I use react-grid and apply overflow: scroll, the full table does not render, only the visible part and the rest of the scroll remains blank.

[Click here to view the gif React Grid with overflow scroll enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBI5G.gif)

[Click here to view the gif React Grid without overflow scroll enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpLwB.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. I was setting the overflow: scroll in the browser through inspect element. Reactgrid seems to be using the width defined ahead of time when the component is first rendered for its calculations. Setting overflow: scroll in my css file and loading the page resolved the issue.